# How to pass the action and controller to the @Url.action call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, url.action

I would like to pass the action name and controller name to the @Url.action call within a Javascript function as variables.  Is there a method to achieve this?

```
function list_onSelectionChanged(e) {
    var strActionName = "Map";
    var strControllerName = "PMO";
    $("#content").load("@Url.Action(strActionName,strControllerName)");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify the script as follows:

```
function list_onSelectionChanged(e) {
    var url = e.addedItems[0].path;
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
}
```

Even simpler:

$("#content").load(url);

This allows a variable to be passed for the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass them *from client-side code* in this way because the server-side code has already run at that point.  Specify them directly in the server-side operation:

```
function list_onSelectionChanged(e) {
  $("#content").load("@Url.Action("Map", "PMO")");
}
```

Note that it *looks like* the syntax will fail because of nested double-quotes.  However, keep in mind that the Razor parser identifies the server-side code separately from the client-side code.  So this is the entire server-side operation:

```
Url.Action("Map", "PMO")
```

And the *result* of that operation is emitted to the client-side code:

```
$("#content").load("result_of_server_side_operation");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I was able to modify my script as follows:
function list_onSelectionChanged(e) {
        var url = e.addedItems[0].path;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    }